# Missing IPN how to diagnose?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

We have been running IPN payments for around 15 months now, and for all that time we have around 10% missed IPN notification (there is no record of PayPal attempting to contact our website to notify it of the IPN, Paypal IPN history gets always http200.

Now we are hitting around 5 missed notification per 30 orders/day. We have tried to set up manually url listener in account settings and after that we are getting hundreds notifications from ebay sales) and also passing url method was used - nothing helped. Any idea how to diagnose the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Something almost certainly must be different about these transactions if PayPal is deciding it does not need to send IPNs on them. Have you looked through the buttons/APIs that are used to generate them, and/or looked closely at the payments in the PayPal system (via the web interface or APIs) to suss out what differs? If you cannot find anything obvious, collect two very similar transactions (one that sent an IPN and one that did not), have the full details of both transactions at hand, and call PayPal support.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is possible some situations don't trigger IPN, IPN actually covers a lot of things. I'd recommend getting in contact with paypal merchant technical services (or with paypal customer support, and they will transfer you to technical) as soon as possible, and ask them to see if there's anything wrong on either side. You would need to prepare the related transaction is within 28 days whose IPN is missing, because IPN only remains in the history for 28 days.

Comment: Thanks guys, We have done some tests and just realized the everything is working correctly when the IPN return url is set manually in paypal account settings (we have some server outages recently and didnt noticed that paypal disabled IPN in account settings!)

So our problems have to be connected with with passing IPN url during transaction....